# Getting app to launch in Chromium using Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dartium

I wanted to know if anyone is having trouble getting Cmd-r to launch their app?

It does bring up chromium, but I must then manually type localhost:3030 and then navigate to my actual app. Furthermore  even after navigating to the app, the server connection eventually times out with

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

I am on a OS X 10.7.5, Dart Editor version 0.4.2_r20259. Thank you.

**4/25/2013: Just to add details about what does not work, here is the error I get when I attempt to compile with the pre-release dartEditor mentioned by Devon Carew:**

```
--- Mar 25, 2013 11:13:59 AM build.dart --machine --changed=web/quizry3.html ---
file:/Users/stephen/silly2/quizry-client/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Uncaught Error: Class '_File' has no instance method 'open' with matching arguments.

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'open'
Receiver: Instance of '_File@0x1da10ec4'
Tried calling: open(Instance of 'FileMode')
Found: open(mode)
Stack Trace:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1884:25)
#1      ConsoleFileSystem.writeString (package:web_ui/src/file_system/console.dart:22:43)
#2      writeFile (package:web_ui/dwc.dart:104:27)
#3      emitFiles.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/dwc.dart:92:35)
#4      List.forEach (dart:core-patch:1219:8)
#5      emitFiles (package:web_ui/dwc.dart:92:18)
#6      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/dwc.dart:86:29)
#7      _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:463:24)
#8      _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#9      _FutureImpl._chain (dart:async:418:23)
#10     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:429:27)
#11     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#12     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#13     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#14     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#15     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#16     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#17     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#18     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#19     _CompleterImpl.complete (dart:async:190:21)
#20     FutureGroup.add.<anonymous closure> (package:web_ui/src/utils.dart:139:28)
#21     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:463:24)
#22     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#23     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#24     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#25     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#26     _CatchErrorFuture._sendValue (dart:async:485:14)
#27     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#28     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#29     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#30     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#31     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#32     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#33     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#34     _FutureListenerWrapper._sendValue (dart:async:221:21)
#35     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#36     _FutureListenerWrapper._sendValue (dart:async:221:21)
#37     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#38     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#39     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#40     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#41     _FutureListenerWrapper._sendValue (dart:async:221:21)
#42     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#43     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#44     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#45     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#46     _CompleterImpl.complete (dart:async:190:21)
#47     _SendPortImpl.call.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch:106:27)
#48     _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:81:92)


Unhandled exception:
Class '_File' has no instance method 'open' with matching arguments.

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'open'
Receiver: Instance of '_File@0x1da10ec4'
Tried calling: open(Instance of 'FileMode')
Found: open(mode)
#0      _FutureImpl._scheduleUnhandledError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:391:9)
#1      Timer.run.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:2362:21)
#2      Timer.run.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:2370:13)
#3      Timer.Timer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch:15:15)
#4      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6385:28)
#5      _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6393:7)
#6      _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:6401:23)
#7      _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:81:92)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pre-release version *may* fix the connection refused issue for you:

http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-editor-archive-trunk/20424/

Comment: Well, the good news is that it does work. It now launches the connection properly. The bad news is that it does not compile the code anymore. :/

If I go to a previous dartEditor though, and then compile the code, and then switch over to the above dartEditor, it does launch properly though. So, looking forward to next version.